# Fazer macro com loop mudando o numero da linha

Tags: excel-vba

Boa tarde!

Preciso com urgencia fazer uma macro em loop que faça isso:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("BT8").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("AF8")
Range("F8:K8").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

E no proximo salto ela mude o range para o proximo numero.

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("BT9").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("AF9")
Range("F9:K9").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Esta é uma maneira meio "tosca" de fazer, mas funciona.
Você só precisa saber a quantidade de linhas limite que vai trabalhar.

```
Sub TESTE()

Dim linha As Double

    For linha = 8 To qtd_linhas

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("BT" & linha).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("AF" & linha)
        Range("F" & linha & ":K" & linha).Select
        Selection.ClearContents

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui adaptar essa estrutura a minha realidade e funcionou perfeitamente.